# How to shutdown graphical interface on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: graphics, gui, 17.04

I've tried the classic `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop` but got a command not found error message.

I also tried the newer `sudo service lightdm stop` but then I stuck on a CLI where I cannot input anything...

Comment: Maybe if you change to a TTY before stopping `lightdm` it will work.

Comment: @MichaelBay: That's not a comment, but an answer.  **:-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually because you didn't activate the terminal interface before shutting down the x server. Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> to enter it or modifying the `/etc/default/grub` `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` => `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"` before `sudo update-grub` and `reboot`. Also, try `sudo systemctl stop lightdm` if `sudo service lightdm stop` doesn't work.